# XCode 9.4.1 >> Simulator iPhone 8 Plus OS 11.4 issue

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios11.4

I have recently installed XCode 9.4.1 on my MAC, current MAC OS is 10.13.4. When I run application on simulator (iPhone 8 plus with iOS 11.4) or on any other simulator which is having iOS 11.4. It is giving me below warning and simulator doesn't run application though it is getting open backside,

[image]

Kindly suggest me an appropriate solution to come out from this issue.

Comment: Hey @jignesh, I am also facing same issues, it only runs on iPhone X simulator. Please suggest